# NAT off on main router but second two routers will have NAT any Security Concerns?

Tags: networking, router, nat

This is what i've read somewhere

( Instead of turning off NAT on the main router, you may consider configuring the main router to pass through the necessary traffic to the two other routers without performing NAT on it. This way, you can avoid the security concerns associated with turning off NAT while still allowing the two other routers to handle NAT for their respective networks. )

Would this be a good Idea as I dont want double NAT and hence ~I would like to turn off NAT on the Main router and the second router will do NAT will their be any security concerns?

The second router will be used as a private network
(Topology) Modem > Main router (No bridgemode) > Secondary & Thirdary routers
all on their own internal ip's

Comment: hope this helps https://youtu.be/7rb8iNj_rJI?t=5

Comment: If the first router only has the second router as a device and the second router is the only router with NAT and if all devices hang off the second router, then security issues are just standard - not better or worse

Answer (score 0):

It's not a security issue. You use firewalls to solve the security issues – and you can still have firewall rules even without NAT; they do not affect each other. (Indeed even with NAT enabled, a firewall is still required to avoid local packets entering.)

More likely though is that it just won't work. The main purpose of such NAT is to ensure that packets going out to Internet have publicly reachable return addresses (i.e. so that servers could reply to you). But if your internal routers have private addresses (and NAT to their own address as is typical), then it is completely useless for them to NAT anything – you're still sending packets with private addresses out to the Internet, just as if you didn't have NAT at all.

It would only work if you had multiple public IP addresses, one for each router. If you only have one address and that's assigned to the edge router, then you pretty much have to NAT at the edge.